# Caffe: g_registry_ in Layer_factory.cpp is not deleted?

Tags: c++, caffe

I'm learning caffe source code. In Layer_factory.cpp I found this:

```
template <typename Dtype>
typename LayerRegistry<Dtype>::CreatorRegistry&
LayerRegistry<Dtype>::Registry() {
  static CreatorRegistry* g_registry_ = new CreatorRegistry();
  return *g_registry_;
}
```

CreatorRegistry is defined in Layer_factory.hpp:

```
typedef std::map<string, Creator> CreatorRegistry;
```

The `g_registry_` is used for storing name-creator pair for layer.

My question is where I can find "delete" operation for `g_registry` since it's created by a "new"? Textbook says new and delete must be used in pair...

Comment: It's a singleton what makes you think they want to delete it until the program terminates?

Comment: @Richard Critten, textbook says new and delete must be used in pair..